# MacBook > Profiles > Remote Management > Certificate expiring. What happens if I let it expire?

Tags: macbook, certificate, remote

In System Preferences > Profiles > Remote management, it says the certificate is about to expire.

Looks like a typical corporate MacBook whose settings were not fully erased before resale.

Under "rights", the certificate lets the company do all kinds of scary things. Erase data on the computer, lock the screen, etc.

There's an "update" button, should I push it?

What happens if I let this certificate expire?

Will I be unable to log into the machine? Lose my data?

Or will a remote admin somewhere no longer be able to control my machine but I can go about my business independently?

Answer (score 0):

> Or will a remote admin somewhere no longer be able to control my machine but I can go about my business independently?

Very likely this, but it depends on exactly what is set in the remote management profile. In the best case (for you), the entire profile will simply expire and auto-delete itself, and the Profiles icon will disappear from System Preferences since there will no longer be any profiles installed.

If you push the "update" button, your MacBook will probably attempt to contact the corporate Active Directory and/or Mobile Device Management system. If that process can complete successfully without you being a corporate employee and knowing the right username+password, the corporate security practices will need some improvement. (Even if the corporate has gone for maximum user-friendliness, the auto-renewal should have been blocked at the corporate side before the MacBook was resold.)

If you own the MacBook, you should have administrator-level access to it. If that's true, you should be able to remove the profile entirely using the `profiles` command-line tool.

Apparently the only way to create a profile in macOS that cannot be removed by a local user with admin access would be to enroll the system in Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager. And if that has been done, it really should have been un-enrolled before resale - otherwise it might cause suspicion that the MacBook was not in fact resold but stolen from the corporate.